# Different keys in Mapper & Combiners

Tags: java, hadoop

In Map-Reduce, is it possible to have different type of keys propagated between Mappers, Combiners and Reducers.

For example, if I have a mapper (implemented in Java) which outputs Text,IntWritable as key/value pairs.
Then, in combiner I consolidate all the output as single key and want to output that as NullWritable, Text. 
and Then in Reducer, I want to output Text, IntWritable.

Is it possible to do something like above ? If not, why ?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify different key/value types for mapper and reducer with methods:

```
job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
```

and

```
job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
```

But you can't set key/value types for combiner different from mapper. That's because combiners are used only to reduce the amount of data that would be sent from mapper to reducer. You should be able to remove combiners without any side effects. But if your combiner produces `NullWritable, Text` pairs and mapper produces `Text, IntWritable` pairs, then your program would fail without combiner.

Comment: Basically, are you saying that all mappers, combiners & reducers should always have the same input/output key/value types ?

Comment: No =) I just tried to explain why there is no sense in different output key/value types for mappers and combiners. Your program should not depend on whether or not the combiners are enabled. Combiners are used only for reduce the amount of data that would be transfered from mappers to reducers, they should not contain any other logic, so you should be able to remove combiners without any side effects.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Text instead of IntWritable:

- Mapper output: Text,Text
- Combiner: Text,Text. As Combiner output key NullWritable can be used.
- Reducer input: Text,Text

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop does use of Combiner for optimization of processing, but not guarantee the Combiner execution. Therefore, you couldn't assuming that, and Hadoop could send the map output data to Reducer phase directly.

For a discussion about this, I recommended read the Chapter 3 of [this book](http://lintool.github.io/MapReduceAlgorithms/MapReduce-book-final.pdf). In the page 48 of the PDF file comment about that problem.